# How to read the data of Adience benchmark(data set for gender and age classification)?

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, dlib

I am trying to train a gender and age classification by cnn, using the data at  [adience](http://www.openu.ac.il/home/hassner/Adience/data.html#frontalized) and I got two questions.

1 :  According to the website, the bounding box of the faces are recorded in the fields "x,y,dx,dy". As an example, from fold_frontal_0_data.txt,the first data is

```
image name  : 10424815813_e94629b1ec_o.jpg  
(x,y,dx,dy) : 301 105 640 641
```

However, the data of the bounding box is weird, because the size of the image is 600x601 only, no matter I treat (x,y,dx,dy) as (left, top, width, height) or (left, top, right, bottom), I cannot crop the face as expected. How could I crop the face properly?

2 : Do I need to do face alignment on training data? Or I only need to do face alignment when testing?Or both?Thanks

This is the image--10424815813_e94629b1ec_o.jpg
[image: 10424815813_e94629b1ec_o.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the other guy who dealing with Adience dataset.

File name of image you uploaded is

> coarse_tilt_aligned_face.2.10424815813_e94629b1ec_o.jpg

not

> image name  : 10424815813_e94629b1ec_o.jpg

If you see README.txt precisely, you can find

> original_image - the filename. Unfortunately we are unable to provide
>   a URL, as we only have the file name and there is no way to reproduce
>   it from the API. A link to the account is provided for accrediting.

(x,y,dx,dy) informations are should be gained from original_image.

Comment: and aligned images are provided also in dataset

Comment: faces are before faces aligned / aligned for after faces aligned